# How to update object based on id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of object:

```
employee = [
    {
      name: 'ashish',
      id: 1,
      date: '2020-11-12',
      gender: 'male',
      designation: 'developer'
    },
    {
      name: 'mishra',
      id: 2,
      date: '2020-10-08',
      gender: 'female',
      designation: 'tester'
    }
]
```

in my button click function i am getting id and it's data. I want to update that record which id matches with any object id of my array

I tried this.

```
editEmployee(id,data) {
    this.employee.find(item => item.id == id).name = this.employee;
  }
}
```

but getting error: `Type '{ name: string; id: number; date: string; gender: string; designation: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'string'`

any solution for it?

Comment: Why are you setting the `name` property of the object to `this.employee` array?

Comment: @adiga just i was debugging, i want to update whole object belongs to that id.

Comment: Does `data` have the full employee object of that `id`?

Comment: You can try either `const i = this.employee.findIndex(e => e.id === id); this.employee[i] = data` OR `Object.assign(this.employee.find(e => e.id === id), data)`

Comment: @adiga it's not working, it is creating one more object with index -1

Comment: If `i` is `-1`, then the `id` is not present in the array. What should be done in that case?

Comment: id is present. may be type casting issue is there. in my object id is int

Comment: What is the type of `id` parameter. Is it a string?

Comment: @adiga i made == instead of === and its working. please put it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do :

```
editEmployee(id,data) {
return this.employee.map(item => item.id == id ? data : item )
 }
```

**Update**

```js
var employee = [
    {
      name: 'ashish',
      id: 1,
      date: '2020-11-12',
      gender: 'male',
      designation: 'developer'
    },
    {
      name: 'mishra',
      id: 2,
      date: '2020-10-08',
      gender: 'female',
      designation: 'tester'
    }
]
function editEmployee(id,data) {
  return employee.map(item => item.id === id ? data : item )
 }
 employee = editEmployee(1,{name:"youba"})
 console.log(employee)
```

Comment: why you're using this in this case?

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe ?

```
editEmployee(id,data) {
    this.employee.find(item => item.id == id) =  {
      name: data.name,
      id: id,
      date: data.date,
      gender: data.gender,
      designation: data.designation
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: error: The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access

Comment: i think i need to see more of your code to see the root of the problem because from a  quick search for the new error i saw this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413733/angular-error-the-left-hand-side-of-an-assignment-expression-must-be-a-variable

Comment: This code is invalid regardless of what OP's code looks like. Run it in the console and it will throw the error mentioned by OP. `const a = [{ id: 1}]; a.find(b => b.id === 1) = { id: 2 }`